# Can't create compute account in Azure, using veeam

Tags: azure, entra-domain-services, veeam, rbac

I can't create a compute account in Azure, using veeam...
I'm trying to create a new linux veeam appliance in Azure, but before i must create an azure compute account,

My user is global administrator, and subscription owner, but it never works... im getting a error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5hIy.png)

Looking into the logs i got this info:

```
[16.01.2024 09:59:25.412]    <15>    Info (3)    [HttpClient] Sending request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
[16.01.2024 09:59:25.813]    <15>    Info (3)    [HttpClient] Request completed
[16.01.2024 09:59:25.813]    <18>    Info (3)    Registering Azure compute account using Device Code flow
[16.01.2024 09:59:26.991]    <18>   Error (3)    Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
[16.01.2024 09:59:26.991]    <18>   Error (3)    Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

i follow the steps in this doc:

[text](https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/hyperv/restore_azure_acc_account_new.html?ver=120)

And i tried applying this custom role to my user...

[text](https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/vsphere/azure_custom_role.html?ver=120)

I need more permissions?, im doing something wrong?...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Veaam docs, the account needs to more than only owner

*when adding a Microsoft Azure Compute account, the application must have the Contributor, Key Vault Crypto User and Storage Queue Data Contributor role privileges for the selected subscription.*

And please check that the following is enabled
enable the **Users can register applications** option for the user in Azure portal.